# Getting a string preview

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, character

What i'm looking for is a way to make a preview of a string. lets say that my string is 150 characters long. But I only want to show the first 50 characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `s.Substring(0,Math.Min(s.Length,50))`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Math.Min`?

Comment: Oops.  Yes it should be.  Doh!

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example using String.Format and string.Substring(). This principle can be applied almost anywhere.

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // let's make a pseudo-random long string
            var longString = new StringBuilder("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789");
            var r = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks);

            for (int i = 0; longString.Length < 256; i++)
            {
                longString.Insert(r.Next(0, longString.Length - 1)
                                  , (!(Math.IEEERemainder(i, 3) < 0.5)
                                         ? longString[i].ToString().ToUpper()
                                         : longString[i].ToString()));
            }


            // Let's see what our long string looks like...
            Console.WriteLine(longString);

            // Now, let's display the first 50 characters of our long string
            // followed by "..." to indicate that there is more.
            var shortstring = String.Format("{0}...",longString.ToString().Substring(0, 50));
            Console.WriteLine(shortstring);

            //Wait for user to hit a key while results are reviewed.
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That would be

```
string s = "150 characters.....";
s.Substring(0,50);
```

Comment: Do this is you want your code to explode in your face.  Substring is not safe to call if either parameter causes the returned value to try and go past the end of the original string.

Comment: @Malcolm Yes, I see the issue, but the OP stated that his string was 150 characters long. If the string length is unknown, then Robs answer would be the way to go.